# Multiple Foreign Keys in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm setting up a database where we are tracking the 'trips' a vehicle takes. Each trip has only one starting point and one ending point, so my first idea was:

```
    trips:
      id (int) - primary key
      location_start (int) - foreign key
      location_end (int) - foreign key
    locations:
      id (int) - primary key
      name(text)
```

location_start and location_end would store the id from the location table.  However, I don't see how to manage this in Eloquent, and when I build this structure using vertabelo.com, I get an error message of "Reference Name Must be Unique"

Should I be using a pivot table for this?  If so, I don't see how to enforce the relationship of each trip can have only two locations, a start and end point.

Comment: I don't know about Eloquent but the error you get in [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com) is because you have two references between trips and locations, and Vertabelo automatically gave it the same name. You have to change the name of the reference (foreign key): click on one of the lines and edit reference name.

Your design seems OK for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I changed the reference and that sorted it. The error in Vertabelo was making me doubt myself!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

In your case, create a migration contain something like this

```
Schema::table('trips', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('location_start')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('location_start')->references('id')->on('locations');
});
```

The last things, foreign key definitions is defined at schema builder, not in Eloquent.